# Graph: N Robots and M Nodes

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, interview-questions

I was recently told I need to change my coding style. An Interviewer told me he would like to see "more formalized class structure and organization". I have attached few of my cpp files.

if you can you review it and give me your feedback on the things I can improve that will be extremely helpful.

#### Challenge:

Given n robots (n different paths), m nodes, how much time all the robots requires to complete the circuit. If 2 robots arrive at a node, the 2nd robot should wait till the 1st robot completes its task.

File structure:

```
├── Solution
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── ***.csv
│   │   ├── ***.csv
│   │   ├── ***.csv
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── robot.h
│   │   ├── node.h
│   │   ├── simulation.h
│   ├── output
│   │   ├── ***.csv
│   │   ├── ***.csv
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   ├── planner.cpp
│   │   ├── read_write.cpp
│   │   ├── simulation.cpp
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── simulationTest.cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── README.md
```

simulation.h

```cpp
#pragma once

...//all headers

#include "robot.h"
#include "node.h"

class simulation{
private:
  std::string robots_ip_string;  
  std::string paths_ip_string;  
  std::string nodes_ip_string; 
  std::string time_op_string;
  std::string visits_op_string;
  std::vector<robot*> robots;  //stores the robot info
  std::unordered_map<int, node*> nodes;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> paths;

public:

  simulation();
  ~simulation();

  void read_robots_input();
  void read_paths_input();
  void read_nodes_input();

  void print_robots();
  void print_nodes();
  void print_paths();
  void run_simulation();
  void simulation_time();
  void visited_node_info();
  std::vector<robot*> get_robots();
};
```

robot.h

```cpp
#pragma once

struct robot{
  int robot_id;
  std::string robot_type;
  int robot_speed;
  std::vector<int> path_to_follow;
  int path_length;
  int run_time;  
};
```

planner.cpp

```cpp
#include "simulation.h"

struct Path_Queue_Comparator{
  bool operator() (std::pair<robot*,int> const& r1, std::pair<robot*,int> const& r2){
    if (r1.first->run_time == r2.first->run_time)
      return (r2.first->robot_type == "organizer") ? true : false;
    return r1.first->run_time > r2.first->run_time;
  }
};

void simulation::run_simulation(){
  std::priority_queue< std::pair<robot*,int>, std::vector<std::pair<robot*,int>>, Path_Queue_Comparator> path_q;

  for(auto r: robots)
    path_q.push({r, 0});

  while(!path_q.empty()){
    std::pair<robot*,int> temp = path_q.top();   

    robot* current_state = temp.first;  
    int current_index = temp.second;    
    path_q.pop();

    int next_index = current_index+1;

    if(current_index < current_state->path_length){                 
      int node_idx = current_state->path_to_follow[current_index]; 
      int wait_time;

      int task_time = (current_state->robot_type == "organizer") ?
          nodes[current_state->path_to_follow[current_index]]->task_time_organizer_robot
              : nodes[current_state->path_to_follow[current_index]]->task_time_mover_robot;

      if (current_state->run_time >= nodes[node_idx]->leave_time){  
          wait_time = 0;
          nodes[node_idx]->entry_time = current_state->run_time;
          nodes[node_idx]->leave_time = current_state->run_time + task_time;
      }
      else{                                                         
        wait_time = nodes[node_idx]->leave_time - current_state->run_time;
        nodes[node_idx]->entry_time = current_state->run_time + wait_time;
        nodes[node_idx]->leave_time = current_state->run_time + wait_time + task_time;
      }

      current_state->run_time += wait_time;
      current_state->run_time += task_time;

      if(next_index <  current_state->path_to_follow.size())
        current_state->run_time +=  current_state->robot_speed; 

      nodes[node_idx]->visited_robots.insert(current_state);

      path_q.push({current_state, next_index});
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I usually code (other files are similar). Please let me know the things I need to change in my coding style! It will be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Comment: @Emma challenge: Given n robots (n different paths), m nodes, how much time all the robots requires to complete the circuit. If 2 robots arrive at a node, the 2nd robot should wait till the 1st robot completes its task.

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid storing redundant data in classes

I see variables like these in `class simulation`:

```
std::string robots_ip_string;
std::string paths_ip_string;
std::string nodes_ip_string;
...
```

Usually, repeating the name of the type in the name of a variable is unnecessary, so at first sight I would say: why not just call them `robots_ip`, `paths_ip`, and so on? However, a closer look shows that there is also:

```
std::vector<robot*> robots;
std::unordered_map<int, node*> nodes;
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> paths;
```

This looks to me like you read the input into a string, and them later convert the textual input into more structured data. But is it really necessary to keep the input strings around? I would remove the `*_string` member variables, and ensure that any function that reads input stores it in a local variable in that function, and them immediately converts it into the vectors and maps.

Another potentially case of redundant information is in `struct robot`:

```
struct robot{
  ...
  std::vector<int> path_to_follow;
  int path_length;
  ...
};
```

A `std::vector` knows how long it is. Instead of storing `path_length`, maybe you can get the same information from calling `path_to_follow.size()`? If so, I would remove `path_length`.

## Separate input/output as much as possible from logic

In `class simulation`, there are `read_*_input()` functions, `print_*()` functions, `run_simulation()` and a few other functions, most of them take no arguments and return `void`. If I see a function like:

```
void read_robots_input();
```

Then I cannot tell where it is reading the input from. Is it from a file, standard input, the network? If it's from a file, which filename? Also, why are there three different `read_*_input()` functions? Would you ever use one but not the others? Also, what if I create an instance of  `class simulation` but never call `read_*_inputs()`? Here are a few suggested changes:

- Have the constructor read all required inputs. This way, after creating an instance of `class simulation`, you know that it is in a valid state and ready to run the simulation.
- Have a way to tell the constructor which inputs to read. This could be three filenames, or even better three references to [`std::istream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) objects, so that the constructor no longer cares if the input comes from a file, a stringstream or anything else with the `std::istream` interface.

Note that this doesn't mean you have to put everything into the constructor itself, you can still have `private` helper functions that parse the individual files and call those from the constructor.

For writing the output, use (a) function(s) that takes references to `std::ostream` objects. Again, this allows the caller to decide whether to print to a file or to `std::cout` for example.

What do `simulation_time()` and `visited_node_info()` do? Do they *print* this information somewhere? If so, make it clear from the name, and have them match the other `print_*()` functions.

## Use an `enum class` for `robot_type`

Using an [`enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for `robot_type` will avoid expensive string comparisons such as in:

```
return (r2.first->robot_type == "organizer") ? true : false;
```

Instead, make it so you can write it like:

```
return r2.first->robot_type == RobotType::ORGANIZER;
```

## Avoid repeating the name of a class in its member variables

Again, the goal is to avoid being redundant and repeating yourself. `struct robot` can be written as:

```
struct robot{
  int id;
  RobotType type;
  int speed;
  std::vector<int> path_to_follow;
  int path_length;
  int run_time;  
};
```

## Call `continue/break/return` early to reduce indentation levels

In `run_simulation()`, there is a big `if`-statement that contains most of the code. However, you can just do with a very small `if`-statement that goes to the next iteration of the loop:

```
while(!path_q.empty()){
  ...

  if(current_index == current_state->path_length)
    continue;

  int node_idx = ...
  ...
}
```

## Use more `auto`, structured bindings

Avoid repeating types by using `auto`. For example:

```
std::pair<robot*,int> temp = path_q.top();
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
auto temp = path_q.top();
```

If you can use C++17, then it becomes even easier to unpack the pair:

```
auto [current_state, current_index] = path_q.top();
```

## Use references as aliases

I see the following piece of code repeated more than once:

```
nodes[current_state->path_to_follow[current_index]]->...
```

That's quite long, and it makes it hard to see what is going on. First, you could have used `node_idx` to shorten this to:

```
nodes[node_idx]->...
```

But it would be better to give a clear name to this expression. You can do this by creating a reference, like so:

```
auto &current_node = nodes[node_idx];
```

Then the rest of the code becomes much clearer:

```
int task_time = current_state->type == RobotType::ORGANIZER ?
                current_node->task_time_organizer_robot :
                current_node->task_time_mover_robot;

if (current_state->run_time >= current_node->leave_time) {
    wait_time = 0;
    current_node->entry_time = current_state->run_time;
    ...
```

Note that `current_state` should probably be named `current_robot`, to be consistent.

Comment: By the way, there's just been a nice talk at CppCon about the issue with those `void()` member functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wg1f9Sufyic